# Can BigQuery's PARSE_DATE function deal with ISOWEEK?

Tags: google-bigquery

When doing year over year comparisons, it's handy to be able to compare ISOWEEKs. BigQuery's `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB` function can't deal with ISOWEEK, so my idea was to simply alter the year (+/- 1)  and then getting back the start date of the ISOWEEK's week number via the `PARSE_DATE` function, but

this works:

`SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%G-%V", DATE('2019-04-15'))` -> `2019-16`

this does not work:

`SELECT PARSE_DATE("%G-%V", "2018-16")` -> `1970-01-01`

There exists also a `DATE_TRUNC` function that does give back the start date of an `ISOWEEK` for any given date, so I was expecting the `PARSE_DATE` function to behave in the same way when parsing a string with an `ISOYEAR` and and `ISOWEEK`.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) explicitly lists the `ISOYEAR` `%G` and the `ISOWEEK` `%V` as supported arguments. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform Support here!

I have been investigating and there is an issue with the %V argument and PARSE_DATE function. In the following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/137922101) you will be able to follow the status of the issue while it's being investigated.

If you have further information to add, please feel free to do so in the link I have provided you.